# How do i remove files from a zip file uploaded through kendoUpload? Using jszip

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-upload, jszip

After the user uploads a zipped file, i want to remove the images folder from it before sending it over the network. I am using kendo for uploading, and the existing functionality works fine. I just want to add on the removing images part. This is what i have so far:

```
   function onSelect(e) {
        var file = e.files[0];
        if (endsWith(file.name, '.eds')) {
            var contents = e.target.result;
            var jszip = new JSZip(contents);
            jszip.remove("apldbio/sds/images_barcode");
            fileToSend = jszip.generate({type: "base64", compression: "DEFLATE"});
        }
        e.files[0] = fileToSend;
        openProgressDialog(e.files.length); //this is existing code, works fine
    }
```

`target.result` doesn't seem to exist in the event `e`. And nothing works properly from that point on. `e` should probably be used inside a FileReader object's onload(), (as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15355093/trying-to-leverage-jszip-to-open-and-then-parse-a-specific-file-in-a-zip) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28753043/how-do-i-keep-from-exiting-a-function-until-a-callback-finishes-in-javascript)) but i have no idea how to use a FileReader for my purpose, with kendo Upload.

EDIT:
I did some more reading and now i am using FileReader like this:

```
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        // do the jszip stuff here with e.target.result
    };
    reader.onerror = function (e) {
        console.error(e);
    };  
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

Note : `file = e.files[0]` as in the 1st code block.
With this though, i get the error:

`Failed to execute 'readAsArrayBuffer' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.`

Comment: When I use a debugger on http://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/examples/read-local-file-api.html the type of `evt.target.files[0]` is a File which *is* a Blob. Which browser do you use ?

Comment: I tested http://jsfiddle.net/5xmbnn6g/ in chromium without issue. The two things that I changed from the code you posted are : bind on `change` (the function name suggests otherwise) and use `e.target.files[0]` instead of `e.files[0]`. If you still have the issue, could you create a sample with jsfiddle ?